# Comment on function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

[image]

I found the function by checking the options that is by solving the differential equation given in option b or c .

I got the function as $f(x)=(3x-x^2)/2$

But how can we solve it without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's twice differentiable function therefore, it must be of form $ax^2+bx+c=0$
now as f(0)=0 from this we get c=0 and from f(1)=1 we get a+b=1;
f(2)=1 there from solving equations of f(1) and f(2) i.e a+b=1 and 4a+b=1 we get b=1 and a=-1 therefore required equation is:
$-x^2+x=0$
Now you can satisfy all the options.

Comment: There are many twice derivable function such as $e^x$ ,$\sin x$ etc

Comment: If you take $e^x+c$ then for f(0) $e^0+c=0$ c=-1 and then for f(1) $e^1 -1 =1$ but $e^1$ is not equals to 2, similarly you can prove for sinx.

Comment: @Koolman And that's why I took polynomial function.

Comment: There are infinite twice derivable function . How can we say only this function will satisfy the conditions

Comment: Obviously there are but polynomial function are always continuous and derivable so you should try and use it at first if it satisfies your conditions why would you take a long way? I see it's multiple type question that must mean it's from competitive exams so you shall approach most easy and time saving process. Therefore I recommended you polynomial function, also it depends very much on question as for how you should approach it.

Comment: If the information were different you may have to use some other type of functions.

Comment: Okay, I see then you should definitely use this method as in general JEE ask polynomial functions for this kind of problems they don't mess it up for children so I'd recommend you to try polynomial if it suits it at first.